# rails novalidate when submit clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with multiple buttons, I want one of the buttons to NOT validate the form, specifically required true text box. Here is the button. I do have simple_form gem.

```
<div class="col-md-2"> <%=  f.submit 'Process Custom Amt', class: "btn btn- primary btn-md", name: 'new_order_with_irregular_pmt' %></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, instead of:

```
if @order.save
  redirect_to @order
else
  render "orders/new"
end
```

You could use:

```
if params[:new_order_with_irregular_pmt]
  @order.save(validate: false)
  redirect_to @order
else
  if @order.save
    redirect_to @order
  else
    render "orders/new"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have two different names for each button in the form.

```
<input type="submit" name="validate" value="Submit" />
<input type="submit" name="dont_validate" value="Submit" />
```

then I would check in the controller which one was submitted

```
if params[:dont_validate]
  @order.save(validate: false)
else 
  @order.save
end
```